# How inline edit work in admin ui-components grid magento2?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, inline-editor

Can you please briefly explain how inline edit work in admin ui-components grid in Magento2.

Please explain `controller`, `interface`, and `model`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There are two main files for inline edit in admin grid**

**1)** Ui Component Grid

**2)** Contoller for save data

Let's take an example `vendor: Test` and `module name: Test`

> **Ui Component Grid**

In the following sample code, I have created a UI Component file named `test_mytesting_index.xml` at `app/code/Test/Test/view/adminhtml/ui_component/test_mytesting_index.xml`

**Here you need to pass inline controller to edit inline data**

`<item name="saveUrl" path="test_test/mytesting/inlineEdit" xsi:type="url"/>`

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_columns.ids</item>
    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">mytesting_id</item>
    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveUrl" path="test_test/mytesting/inlineEdit" xsi:type="url"/>
        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

**Now create controller `InlineEdit.php` to get the posted data and save it into the database**

> app/code/Test/Test/Controller/Adminhtml/Mytesting/InlineEdit.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Mytesting;

class InlineEdit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $error = false;
        $messages = [];

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
            $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
            if (!count($postItems)) {
                $messages[] = __('Please correct the data sent.');
                $error = true;
            } else {
                foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $modelid) {
                    /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
                    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Test\Test\Model\Mytesting')->load($modelid);
                    try {
                        $model->setData(array_merge($model->getData(), $postItems[$modelid]));
                        $model->save();
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $messages[] = "[Mytesting ID: {$modelid}]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
}
```

> Use fieldAction to make the grid clickable by the element *fieldAction*

The action *inlineEdit* will save the data into mysql. We will make the grid clickable by the element *fieldAction*

```
<item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_columns_editor</item>
        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

**We will make the column editable inline by using the element editor:**

```
<column name="field1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">field1</item>
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">10</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

In the configuration for the specific column, the editor can include:

**editorType -** type of the editor. Possible values: same as primitives (text, select, date), can also provide new type.

**validation -** validation rules, required-entry here as just an example of possible rules

Comment: Thanks @prince patel
I have tried with 
 
                        $block->setData(array_merge($block->getData(), $postItems[$blockId]));
                       
but getting error <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionSubReport::setData()

Answer (score 0):

**Inline Edit Component**

The Inline Edit component is used to provide the ability of inline editing.

**Related UI Components**

The Bulk Edit component uses the Inline Edit component. The Listing component can use the Inline Edit if it is configured and enabled.

**Implementation of Inline Edit**

Currently Inline Edit is not presented in definition.xml. It is used as a plugin for the Listing component. It can be configured in definitions.xml if necessary.

To enable Inline Edit component for the grid, it is declared as a plugin for Listing component:

**For more detail visit magento** [devdocs.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-inline.html)

Comment: I know how to make admingrid inline editable but i  don't know how inline edit controller and interface work for data save.
Can you please explain it

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this URL,

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-inline.html

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-code-inline-editing-grid-in-magento-2-backend/

This will help you more.

Comment: Actually i  don't know how inlineedit controller and interface work for data save.
Can you please explain it

Comment: If your requirement is to edit grid inline then you follow this. And Magento saves data.

Comment: Check this file: `app\code\Magento\Ui\view\base\web\templates\grid\editing\header-buttons.html`

Comment: When you edit field inline and hit save button then save controller is call from a grid.

Comment: If you read carefully this document then you easily understand how it works.

Comment: Actully i want to understand save functionality which is not explained in document