# How to inline edit magento 2 product collection using ui-components(grid)?

Tags: magento2.2

Suppose i want to edit some rows in product's grid collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the element Columns, You have to register the inline editing.

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_test_list.test_test_list.test_test_columns.ids</item>
   <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
   <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="test/test/inlineEdit"/>
      <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
   </item>
 </item>
```

The action inlineEdit will save the data into the database.

Make the clickable element to edit the data:

```
<item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_test_list.test_test_list.test_test_columns_editor</item>
     <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
     <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
       <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     </item>
   </item>
 </item>
```

Now, make the column editable which we want to edit in the grid using the element editor.

```
<column name="qty">
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
          <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             <item name="validate-zero-or-greater" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
          </item>
       </item>
       <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quantity</item>
       <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
    </item>
  </argument>
</column>
```

**editorType**: Type of the editor such as text, date, select etc.
**validation**: Validation rules which you want to apply before the save.

Create the controller for saving edited data:

> This file will be located under app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Controller/Adminhtml/Test/

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

class InlineEdit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $error = false;
        $messages = [];

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
            $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
            if (!count($postItems)) {
                $messages[] = __('Please correct the data sent.');
                $error = true;
            } else {
                foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $entityId) {
                    /** load your model to update the data */
                    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Test\Test\Model\test')->load($entityId);
                    try {
                        $model->setData(array_merge($model->getData(), $postItems[$entityId]));
                        $model->save();
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $messages[] = "[Error:]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
}
```

For the reference you can check below link

- [how-to-code-inline-editing-grid-in-magento-2-backend](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-code-inline-editing-grid-in-magento-2-backend/)
- [inline-editing-grid-in-magento-2-backend](https://webkul.com/blog/inline-editing-grid-in-magento-2-backend/)
- [how-inline-edit-work-in-admin-ui-components-grid-magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228794/how-inline-edit-work-in-admin-ui-components-grid-magento2)

I hope it helps!

Comment: @paras surya If my answer is useful to you then you can accept as answer.

Comment: yes , it is useful for me.

Comment: So you can accept as answer  just click on Right arrow below upvote button.

Comment: @ChiragPatel How can we implement this functionality on the admin Product grid?
Can you please explain. I've tried above but did not get any luck.

Comment: @ChiragPatel how we can add a max limit for the inline edit rows selection at a time?